# Finding an invertible matrix without calculating the inverse using eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I'm confused about finding the inverse of a matrix with limited information.

> a) Show that the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 9 & 16 & -4\\
> -4 & -7 & 2\\
> 4 & 8 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is diagonalizable, and diagonalize it. You may use use the fact that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and $1$.

I already did this. $P=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -2 & 1\\
-1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

> b) Without doing any further numerical calculations, show that $A$ is invertible and find its inverse. Explain your answer.

I know the matrix is invertible since none of the eigenvalues are zero. How do I find the inverse though?

I attempted the following.

I know for eigenvalues, $Ax=\lambda x$

For $\lambda=1$, we get $Ax=x$ which implies that $Ax-x=0$.

This furthermore implies that $x(A-I)=0$. Since 0 is never an eigenvector, we must have that $A=I$. If I invert both sides, I get $A^{-1}=I^{-1}$ or $A^{-1}=I$ which tells use that $A=A^{-1}$.

For $\lambda=-1$, we get $Ax=-x$ which implies that $Ax+x=0$ or $x(A+I)=0$. This implies that $A=-I$. Similarly, $A^{-1}=-I^{-1}$ or $A^{-1}=-I$ which also implies that $A^{-1}=A$.

Is my logic correct? If it's not, where did I go wrong and how can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You're essentially saying that $A$ equals $I$ and $-I$ in your argument which doesn't make much sense. Also, the only way $Bx=0$ implies $B=0$ (the zero matrix) is if $Bx=0$ for **all** $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$. In other words, you cannot say $(A+I)x=0$ implies $A=-I$ unless this equation is true for all $x$. The only thing $(A+I)x=0$ implies is that $x$ belongs to the kernal of $A+I$. You're also factoring $x$ out on the left incorrectly when you should be factoring $x$ out on the right. If you want to show that $A=A^{-1}$ write $A=PDP^{-1}$ and use the fact that $D=D^{-1}$

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. I attempted it again and I get the following:

So far I have the following:

$A=PDP^{-1}$

$A^{-1}=P^{-1}D^{-1}P$

But $D=D^{-1}$, so we get:

$A^{-1}=P^{-1}DP$.

I see a connection with the first part but I can't quite see it.

Comment: Note: $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$

Comment: Ahh I forgot that. So we have $A=PDP^{-1}$. Taking inverses, we  $A^{-1}=PD^{-1}P^{-1}$. Since $D=D^{-1}$. we get $A^{-1}=PDP^{-1}$. But the right side is just $A$, so we get $A^{-1}=A$. Is that the right idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be much simpler: we know that $D=P^{-1}AP$, which  is equivalent to $A=PDP^{-1}$.

Now, as $D$ is diagonal, it is obvious that $D^2=I$, whence
$$A^2=(PDP^{-1})(PDP^{-1})=PD^2P^{-1}=PP^{-1}=I.$$

Comment: I like this a lot!